# Is it possible to run a php soap api operation in a web browser

Tags: php, soap, apache-axis

In axis2 on Java it's possible to run operations in the browser by the way you send the url

for example

localhost:8080/axis2/services/SimpleService?wsdl

could have operations implemented by writing urls like so

localhost:8080/axis2/services/SimpleService/hello?param0=xxx

My Question is can you do the same in PHP5 SoapServer where the url is as below?

localhost/soaptest/index.php?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

I would use the poster extension for Firefox for this.

Comment: Yes but that wasn't what I trying to do. I was trying to use the PHP SOAP Server in a REST like mannor

Comment: Well, then the answer is no. You'll have to create a parallel REST interface.